# Recursive Factorial of a number using C and NASM

Tags: c, assembly, nasm, factorial

I am trying to find the factorial of a user input number, and display it.

The issue I am facing is that no mater what the input, output is always 1.

[image: wrong output]

The input and output part is done through the C language, as in the code below,

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int factorial(int n);

int main() {
    int n, res;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    res = factorial(n);

    printf("Factorial of %d is: %d\n", n, res);
    return 0;
}
```

and the NASM code containing the logic for the factorial code is as follows,

```
section .text
    global factorial

factorial:
    ; Input:  ecx

    ; Base case
    cmp ecx, 1
    jbe .base_case    

    ; Recursive case
    push ecx ;save n in stack

    ; Recurcive call with n-1
    dec ecx
    call factorial

    pop ecx ;pop from stack

    imul eax, ecx

    ret

.base_case:
    mov eax,1
    ret
```

For better understanding of the code, I have added comments.

And the command I am using to compile this is as follows
`nasm -f elf RecurciveFactorial.asm && gcc -m32 -o RecurciveFactorial RecurciveFactorial.c RecurciveFactorial.o && ./RecurciveFactorial`

I have tried changing the `jbe` to `jle` and changing the order of `imul`, i.e.,
`imul eax,ecx` to `imul ecx,eax`, and also initialize the `eax` register with value 1, but that also dosen't work.

I am also getting this warning -
[image: warning]

This is my first time doing the linking of C and NASM. The `factorial` is being called in the C code, I have tested that part as well.

Help would be highly appreciated, and also tell me whether the warning is of importance or can be ignored.

Comment: @TomKarzes, that is being dealt with by the `jbe` branch.

Comment: Are you sure that the function argument is passed in `ecx` and not in `eax`?

Comment: @WeatherVane ya i tried that as well still not working

Comment: "I have tried changing the `jbe` to `jle`." For values `0` and `1` it won't matter, but generally you should use `jle` for signed and `jbe` for unsigned arithmetic. If you want to catch negative values too (and you should) then use `jle`.

Comment: I have no experience with this, but in your shoes I would first make a simple function that returns the argument passed to it, just to make sure you have the in/out registers right, and then add complexity.

Comment: You should compile your C code to assembly (`-S` option for gcc) and check how your arguments is passed. in 32-bit x86 environment, the arguments are typically passed via the stack, not via registers.

Comment: @ikegami: This code uses both 0 and 1 as base cases (and returns 1 for both), which is perfectly valid.

Comment: What OS are you using?  Calling conventions vary, but under Linux, for instance, function arguments are passed on the stack instead of in registers.  What's your basis for believing the argument is passed in ecx here?

Comment: The executable stack warning is not relevant to your problem, btw, and can be ignored for the time being.

Comment: Your `.note.GNU-stack` makes it very unlikely that you're on Windows, so the first arg is definitely not in ECX.  `gcc -mregparm=3` passes the first arg in EAX (but that would break library functions because they're compiled with the standard stack-arg ABI, so you'd actually want `__attribute__((regparm(3)))` on the prototype).  You could perhaps use `__attribute__((ms_abi, fastcall))` or something on the declaration.  Or just write your code to read the arg from the stack, at `[esp+4]` on function entry.

Comment: Ya the issue has been resolved, Thanks everyone for your help, in making me think what was wrong. The input was in fact coming in eax register not in ecx, and jle is to be used not jbe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first function arg is pass by `rdi` register not `rcx`.

You have high chance to have `0` at base value in `ecx`, and that jump on `base_case`, where you move the `1` to `rax` register you recv.

[You can check here the usage of all register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEwvm.png)

Comment: This is 32-bit code, as we can see from the fact that `push ecx` assembles. (It's an invalid instruction in 64-bit mode).  So the arg is on the stack, at initially at `[esp+4]`, not registers, unless you use `__attribute__((regparm(3)))` on the prototype.  Only x86-64 System V passes the first arg in RDI.  (Or in this case EDI since it's an `int`.)